# Regex to find whitespace in the text of a link

Tags: html, regex

I am trying to write a regex that finds the space in between "Red" and "Blend" in the text of the link.

```
<a title="Show products matching tag Red Blend" href="/collections/50-to-100/red-blend">Red Blend</a>
```

The regex will also need to be able to find both of the spaces in the following block of code:

```
<a title="Show products matching tag Russian River Valley" href="/collections/50-to-100/russian-river-valley">Russian River Valley</a>
```

In both cases I am going to be replacing the space with a non-breaking space character, but that will be handled by my server-side script.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: So you want to capture all of the whitespace inside of the `title` attribute, after `Show products matching tag `?

Comment: What environment are you working in? You shouldn't use regex for this, and chances are that you don't have to.

Comment: TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

Comment: This is actually going to be used in a shopify theme. Shopify theme symtax is based on Rails syntax, and there is a simple replace filter. [Here is a link to the shopify replace filter](http://wiki.shopify.com/Replace).  I don't actually know if regex will work in shopify, so I was planning to do it in javascript as a backup.

Comment: @cheeken No, I am looking for a way to remove the whitespace from the text of the link, not the `title` attribute.

Comment: For those of you flagging @Michael 's comment because you don't get the "Tony the Pony" reference, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ok, thanks for clarifying the Tony the Pony part. I humbly accept my chastisement and vow not to ever try to parse html with regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what language you are using, but if you want to use a little javascript/jQuery, you could do this;

```
var a = $('a').text();
var b = a.replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;');
$('a').html(b);
```

This assumes (from your question) that the space you want to replace is in the text of the link.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/ejJYF/1/

Comment: If are using jQuery, at least use it *right*: `$('a').text(function(i, t) {return t.replace(/\s/g, String.fromCharCode(160)); });`

Comment: Nicely written @Tomalak.  Learned something new

Comment: @Tomalak Great job and thanks so much! Here is my test of Tomalak's jQuery function with a larger set of sample data: http://jsfiddle.net/ejJYF/2/ This should take care of my problem